# Json POST Request data don't get to server in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.2

Hey I'm struggling with that problem. The server gets the request but not the json that i transmit.
I have searched in the threads, but found nothing that works for me.

My Coffescript request:

```
d = { 'filter': "John Portella" };

$.ajax(
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "text/json",
  data : JSON.stringify(d),
  url: "/restricted/actionOnMultipleDatasets",
  success: (data) ->
    ...
```

The related route:

```
POST   /restricted/actionOnMultipleDatasets       controllers.ajax.AjaxDatasetOperations.actionOnMultipleDatasets()
```

and the Controller action

```
@SecuredAction(authorization = WithProvider.class, params = { "userpassword" })
public static Result actionOnMultipleDatasets() {
    UserInfo userInfo = (UserInfo) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);
        JsonNode json=request().body().asJson();
    if(json==null){
        return badRequest(Json.toJson("Data is not Json!"));
    }
```

And every time I request that action the json is null. Does anyone figure out why this happens?
As additional information I use securesocial.

I have tried to clean up the project. Nothing happened.

The related stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.ajax.AjaxDatasetOperations.actionOnMultipleDatasets(AjaxDatasetOperations.java:588)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$36$$anonfun$apply$36.apply(routes_routing.scala:497)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$36$$anonfun$apply$36.apply(routes_routing.scala:497)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
    at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
    at play.GlobalSettings$1.call(GlobalSettings.java:64)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When posting with jquery, try adding the following lines as parameters:

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

dataType: "json",